# How to fastly sort event time tags into multiple bins?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, classification

I have a stream of event time tags (~1'000'000 ) that represent detection events. The time tags are uints that indicate if a detection happened in this time segment. If there is no time tag, then no detection happened in the time segment. The list is monotonically ordered. Besides this, I have a timing table that defines certain channels to which I want to sort the time tags. If one detection event or more happened in a certain time period specified in the time table, then we say that there occurred an event on the respective channel (i.e. for the timing table entry, the result is "True"). The timing table describes a unit of channels that is repeated.

So far, I basically do a nested for loop over all time tags. For each tag, I run a second loop to check against all timing table entries. However, this approach is very slow. Is there any better algorithm to achieve this faster?

Here in pseudo-code what I do:

```
tags = [8,500,1001,1265,1266,1502,1600,2990]
table = [0,1260,1480]
window = 10
single_run_duration = 1500
reps = ceil(max(tags)/single_run_duration)
storage = zero_array(len(table),reps)

for ti in tags:
   for ch in table:
      if ch <= (ti % single_run_duration) <= ch+window:
         run = floor(ti/single_run_duration)
         storage(ch,run) = True
// Storage contains afterwards:
storage = [[True,True],[True,False],[False,False]]
```

EDIT: The windows do not overlap and the table is monotonically ordered as well.

Comment: You can't probably avoid looking at all the tags. You could reduce the cycle over the timing table from linear to log. Assuming the table is sorted and windows do not overlap, `bsearch` with a comparison that considers the window.

Comment: If the input is a stream, should the output (`storage` in the pseudo-code) also be a stream? I.e. transpose `storage` in the pseudo-code: `storage = zero_array(reps, len(table))`, `storage(run,ch) = True`. Result: `storage = [[True, True, False], [True, False, False]]`.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to create a (perfect) hash table from the channel timing table so you avoid an O(N) scan or O(ln N) lookup.

```
storage = np.zeros((len(table), reps), dtype=int)

lookup = [None] * single_run_duration

for ch_index, ch in enumerate(table):
    for i in range(ch, min(ch+window+1, single_run_duration)):
        lookup[i] = [ch_index] if not lookup[i] else lookup[i] + [ch_index]

for ti in tags:
    channels = lookup[ti % single_run_duration]
    if not channels:
        continue
    for ch_index in channels:
        run = math.floor(ti/single_run_duration)
        storage[ch_index, run] = 1
```

in Python, this runs for a million tags and ~300 table entries about 1.9 seconds vs 44 seconds for the linear scan algorithm you present.

This uses as map of time to lists of channel indices, if it was known that the windows never overlap then it could be simplified a bit.

---

Python test infrastructure:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import sys
import timeit


tags = np.cumsum(np.random.randint(1, 501, 1000_000))
table = np.cumsum(np.random.randint(1, 10, 1500))
window = 10
single_run_duration = 1500
table= table[table < single_run_duration - window]
reps = math.ceil(max(tags)/single_run_duration)

# original
def map_1():
   storage = np.zeros((len(table),reps), dtype=int)

   for ti in tags:
      for ch_index, ch in enumerate(table):
         if ch <= (ti % single_run_duration) <= ch+window:
            run = math.floor(ti/single_run_duration)
            storage[ch_index,run] = 1

   return storage

timeit.timeit(map_1, number=1)


# using hashmap
def map_2():
    storage = np.zeros((len(table), reps), dtype=int)

    lookup = [None] * single_run_duration

    for ch_index, ch in enumerate(table):
        for i in range(ch, min(ch+window+1, single_run_duration)):
            lookup[i] = [ch_index] if not lookup[i] else lookup[i] + [ch_index]

    for ti in tags:
        channels = lookup[ti % single_run_duration]
        if not channels:
            continue
        for ch_index in channels:
            run = math.floor(ti/single_run_duration)
            storage[ch_index, run] = 1
    
    return storage


timeit.timeit(map_2, number=1)

assert (map_1() == map_2()).all()
```